# How to generate 3D point cloud data file from multiple images of the object?

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, 3d, computer-vision

Are there any tools or algorithm in Matlab or OpenCv, which will take multiple images of any object as input (from different location around the object) and produce the 3D coordinate of the object in the world.

Comment: Take a look at PCL (Point cloud library)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Naveh said, in OpenCV the building blocks are there, but putting it together is something you would have to do.

That being said, people have generated a number of SfM tools in both C++ and Matlab. Depending on your goals there are a number of prepackaged things you can look at:

-There is a [SfM Matlab Toolbox here](https://code.google.com/p/vincents-structure-from-motion-matlab-toolbox/), I have not personally used it but I've seen it a number of times.

-If you are just looking for a black-box solution, check out [Visual SfM](http://ccwu.me/vsfm/), it is a GUI-fied version of a common SfM workflow.

-A while ago I put together a guide for installing the Visual SfM components individually [on Fedora](http://dirsapps.cis.rit.edu/3d-workflow/install.html), if you wanted to dig into them. I'm not sure how relevant it is now but it might help.

Regardless, you should certainly educate yourself on the processes involved in creating 3D structure from imagery. It is a complicated process with many details which need to be understood.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is a fully fledged structure from motion algorithm. I don't think such a thing exists in MATLAB or OpenCV right off the shelf. However, the building blocks required for such an algorithm are there.

I suggest you do some background reading to better understand what specific algorithm will suit your needs. A good place to start is in Richard Szeliski's textbook, chapter 7. A free draft is available [here](http://szeliski.org/Book/). This book is recommended both in general as a good computer vision textbook, and specifically as well for your question, in which Szeliski himself is quite an expert.